# Render an index template of children in the parent's show template

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework

I have a `User` and an `Email` scaffold (a `user` `has_many` `emails`). I want to display the `Email` `index` template in the `User` `show` if the user has emails. Here is the code:

**web/controllers/user_controller.ex**

```
[...]
def show(conn, %{"id" => id}) do
  user = Repo.get!(User, id) |> Repo.preload([:emails])

  conn
  |> assign(:user, user)
  |> render("show.html")
end
[...]
```

**web/templates/user/show.html.eex**

```
[...]
<%= unless Enum.empty?(@user.emails) do %>
  <%= render MyApp.EmailView, "index.html", emails: @user.emails %>
<% end %>
[...]
```

I get an `assign @conn not available in eex template.` error with that. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're probably using `@conn` in the `index.html` template of the `EmailView`, but `render` doesn't automatically send `@conn` from the current template to the template it's going to render, so you need to do:

```
<%= render MyApp.EmailView, "index.html", conn: @conn, emails: @user.emails %>
```